# reproduce java logic control in if()

Tags: java, netlogo, porting

what is the most efficient way to translate this Java code into Netlogo:

```
boolean cont = true;
for (int i = 0; cont && i < 10; i++) {
  if (condition) {
    // do stuff
      cont = false;
  }
}
```

I have tried something along this line:

```
let cont true
while [cont][
  foreach a-list [
    if (condition)[
      ;; do stuff
      set cont false
    ]
  ]
]
```

but it's not as efficient because the foreach might end and the while condition won't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stop`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/stop.html) to break out of a procedure. Be careful, though: `stop` exits from the whole procedure, not just the loop. This can be dealt with by enclosing the relevant code in it's own procedure:

```
to loop-through-list
  foreach a-list [
    if condition? [ stop ]
    ; do stuff...
  ]
  print "Be careful: this line won't execute!"
end
```

A bit of general advice: NetLogo has its own way of doing things, and it's very different from Java. In particular, I would suggest avoiding indexes and `while` loops in your NetLogo code. They can usually be replaced by [`foreach`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/foreach.html) or [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/map.html), which lead to more robust and maintainable code.

Comment: I see... it could also be a report procedure? instead of calling stop, I just call report...

Comment: Yes, `report` would also break out of the whole procedure.